# Determining server functions on thrift

Tags: c++, thrift

I would like to have a client connect to the server and determine what functions the process is accepting with the parameter and return types.

I'm already able to connect to a service and

The language I would like to do this in is C++.

Does the Thrift API allow provide a method for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think general thrift allows for such querying, you need to have thrift idl files upfront and compile them.

If you can control server, you could have some querying layered a top of thrift.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I guess I'll have to think of something else.  Thanks for your time.